# Running external selenium script from Groovy[SOAPUI]

Tags: selenium, groovy, soapui

I see online that the way to run a simple python file from groovy is:

```
def cmdArray2 = ["python", "/Users/test/temp/hello.py"]
def cmd2 = cmdArray2.execute()
cmd2.waitForOrKill(1000)
log.info cmd2.text
```

If hello.py contains - Print "Hello". It seems to work fine

But when I try to run a .py file containing the below Selenium code nothing happens.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time



driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe')

driver.get("http://www.google.com") # Load page

# 1 & 2 
title = driver.title
print title, len(title)
driver.quit()
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
FYI - I have tried using all the browsers including headless browsers but no luck.

Also, I am able to run the selenium script fine from the command line. But when I run from the SOAPUI, I get no errors, the script runs and I do not see anything in the log

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you do not see any errors from your python script because they are printed to stderr not stdout (as you expected when called cmd2.text). Try this groovy script to check error messages from python script stderr

```
def cmdArray2 = ["python", "/Users/test/temp/hello.py"] 
def process = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArray2).redirectErrorStream(true).start()
process.inputStream.eachLine {
    log.warn(it)
}
process.waitFor()
return process.exitValue()
```

Another thing you might want to try is using selenium directly from groovy without calling external python script.